# How to add Array join method inside an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

```
var person = {  
address: [
    '308 Congress Street',
    'Boston',
    'Massachusetts'
]
}
```

How to insert Array join method in `"address"` and display all Array item.

The result would be like this: `308 Congress Street, Boston, Massachusetts`

Comment: `person.address.join(', ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this..use array's `join()` method.`join()` method joins all array elements into a single string.

```js
var person = {  
address: [
    '308 Congress Street',
    'Boston',
    'Massachusetts'
]
}

alert(person.address.join(', '));//OR alert(person['address'].join(', '));
```

Comment: glad to help you.enjoy and best of luck ahead.

Comment: try using both ways.

Comment: just `person.address.join(',');` is not enough for you because you also want to a space.so `person.address.join(', '); is correct.`

Answer (score 1):

Use Join like this

```
person.address.join(',')
```

Comment: Happy to Help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You try this.

```
alert(person.address.join(', '));
```

Here is detail.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last index of the `address` array to be the combined values, just do...

```
person.address.push(person.address.join(', '))
```